# Problems ( madness ) with MySql collation

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

All my tables have been set to latin1_general_ci
Im using innoDB all round.
When i create a new (blank) stored procedure in (MySqlWorkbench) and run it, i get the following bizarre nonsense:

> 0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1267 Illegal mix of collations
>   (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for
>   operation '='

The stored procedure is empty. It is doing absolutely nothing.
So why this stupid collation message?

Ps. i know this problem has troubled a lot of people over the years.
And i have found plenty of lame workarounds and crack pot ideas for solutions.
But no solutions that seems even remotely sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Going through each table column that is accessed in the stored procedure that i want to create and changing the collation to latin_general_ci like the default should have been, fixes the problem.
The warnings are still there. duh!